# What is meant by "pun intended"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am not a native speaker of English. I came across many articles which used the phrase "pun intended". In many cases I am not able to grasp the meaning of the sentence as what this phrase mean in the context. For example,

> Behavioural experts say it is not just the wiring that causes the ‘differences’ (pun intended).

I am totally clueless about what the meaning of the phrase inside the braces is. What does it mean?

Comment: Can you give some previous sentences to give more context? It's hard to tell what pun/double meaning is being referred to, intended or not.

Comment: @Mitch: It's probably electrical. Electrical voltage is more properly referred to as "potential difference" across a circuit. In certain work/study environments it's often shortened as "difference" instead of voltage. From the snippet, I would assume that the article is about behavioral anomalies caused by voltage fluctuations or variances in certain parts of the brain.

Comment: @Mitch its in some article about behavioral differences between men and women. "wiring" here has references to brain neural connections

Comment: Well, it could be a very poor pun. Or the writer is using the word pun inappropriately.

Comment: @Mitch I also have the same feeling that the writer is using it inappropriately.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Pun intended* means that the joke was a deliberate one.

A pun is a play with a word, e.g. "You can tune a guitar, but you can't tuna fish."

Sometimes authors accidentally do this; that is, they did not mean to play with a word, but a reader can interpret the author's work as a pun.

However, here, it is specifically stating that this pun was *intended*, or *deliberate*.

Answer (score 21):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned that the phrase "pun intended" is a form of wordplay itself:

As others have commented, a *pun* is a play on words, usually using words that sound the same or similar to give multiple meanings to a phrase.

Sometimes when writing or speaking it is hard or unavoidable to use a phrase that creates such a double meaning - potentially obscuring the speaker's point and/or making it seem like they are joking. In this situation it is common for people to say

> (No pun intended)

This, I believe, is the original phrase.

Playing on this, some people occasionally reverse the phrase by removing the negative:

> pun intended

to make it clear to the listener that yes, they are using wordplay to make their point.

(Interestingly Google has ~11 million hits for ["pun intended"](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22pun+intended%22&aq=f&aqi=g-c1g1g-c3&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2ecdb1aa5a7c06eb&biw=1635&bih=772), but ~21 million for [no pun intended](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22no+pun+intended%22&aq=f&aqi=g-c3g1g-c1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2ecdb1aa5a7c06eb&biw=1635&bih=772), even though every page that contains "no pun intended" must contain "pun intended"!)

Comment: It may not mean anything, but Wiktionary has [an entry for "no pun intended"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_pun_intended), but [none for "pun intended"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pun_intended).

Comment: The problem is that people often say "no pun intended" in order to call attention to the pun.

Answer (score 4):

"Pun intended" literally means "There is a pun (a play on words) in this sentence, and I put it in intentionally."  This distinguishes it from unintentional puns, where the writer didn't mean to put it whatever double-meaning is there.

Unfortunately the example sentence you give doesn't have enough context for us to tell what the pun is; I would guess that either "wiring" or "differences" is used in a slightly different way in the previous sentences.

Answer (score 0):

[Pun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun)

> The pun, also called paronomasia, is a form of word play which suggests two or more meanings, by exploiting multiple meanings of words, or of similar-sounding words, for an intended humorous or rhetorical effect.

*Pun intended* probably is used to indicate that the ambiguous phrase was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as many have explained, "pun intended" means that the pun is deliberate: can't argue with that!
However I think that in many cases the author slyly draws our attention  to the fact that *there is a pun*, which might otherwise have escaped us readers.
Anyway, it often happens to me that I only notice a pun because of this kind of remark, in English of course, but even in my native language, French.

Answer (score 0):

> It means that the person has noticed a potential pun(humorous
>   play on words) in what they have said or written and they want people
>   to know that it was intended.