# '..just kidding.'

Tags: phrase-requests

What's a subtle way of saying 'I'm just kidding' in the same way that a wink cues others to ignore what you just said because it was either a poor joke or just of no importance.

Comment: Please take our [Tour](/tour), and then hover your mouse pointer over that ‘‘[question-tags]’’ tag to see what it means.

Comment: A wink works for that too.

Comment: One has to avoid coming very close to implying 'I'm pretty sure you're not bright enough to have got that joke'. 'It _was_ a bad one, wasn't it' avoids this implication.

Answer (score 1):

> Don’t take it seriously!
>
> Just teasing you!
>
> I’m just pulling your leg.
>
> Just taking the piss out of ya.
>
> I’m only being silly.
>
> I’m just poking fun at you.
>
> I’m just fooling around.
>
> Just trying to take the Mickey.
>
> I’m just messing with you.
>
> It was only a joke.
>
> I’m just having a laugh.
>
> I was only playing around.
>
> I'm only jesting.

Most of these answers were precompiled [here](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/ask/question/other-ways-to-say-just-kidding/)

Comment: These are not subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Simply say, **pun intended**.

> **Example:**
>
> If nobody drowns at the lake, everything will go along swimmingly. Pun intended.

***[What is meant by “pun intended”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/what-is-meant-by-pun-intended)***

> An expression to clarify the use of a pun in a previous statement. Most often employed when a speaker does not trust his audience to recognize the pun on its own.

Add a (~_^) while saying for special effects.

Comment: Hello, Rahul. OP asks for a _subtle_ way of communicating this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: How is it not fitting in definition of **subtle** ? [It's _narrow, precise, clever and indirect_](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=subtle+way+meaning)

Comment: And is arguably a paraphrase of 'Don't fail to notice how clever I am.'

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to come up with a more subtle way of saying, "I'm just kidding," because if the person doesn't already know that you're kidding they may have a general problem with subtlety. That said, if you're just trying to get past an awkward pause after a joke that missed it's mark, you might say "**Never mind**."